# The riddle of the 300

Tags: riddle

> A troop of soldiers: in formation bravely they stand 
>   An ominous rumble is heard across the land 
>   Then, boom! A blast, they are struck down - fallen, slain 
>   But rise from the grave to face danger again

**Explain what this is describing.**

Comment: This is a terrific riddle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Bowling

Explanation:

> The soldiers are pins, in a set formation. The ball comes rumbling towards them and then knocks them all down at once (which is known as a strike). But they are then picked up (usually by a machine) and set up to be bowled at again. The title refers to the maximum possible score in a full game.